# List details of sales persons with a last name has “l” as the third letter. Sort the results by the first name in descending order

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT personid
     , persfname
     , perslname 
  FROM person 
 ORDER 
    BY perslname ('__l%') DESC
```

This is the code I thought it would be but I am having trouble displaying the correct query.

Comment: Use SUBSTRING() function for to extract "third letter" and use direct compare `=`.

Comment: Use WHERE for the filtering, and ORDER BY tp ordet the result.

Answer (score 1):

This will work.

```
SELECT personid
     , persfname
     , perslname 
FROM person 
WHERE perslname LIKE '__I%'
ORDER BY persFname  DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use either `REGEXP` or `SUBSTRING`.

Using `REGEXP`:

```
SELECT personid, persfname, perslname 
FROM person 
WHERE perslname REGEXP '^(.{2}l)'
ORDER BY persfname DESC
```

Using `SUBSTRING`:

```
SELECT personid, persfname, perslname 
FROM person 
WHERE SUBSTRING(perslname, 3, 1)='l'
ORDER BY persfname DESC
```